# how to mark current item text in QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I'm using a combo box as a simple command line with a history.

Here's the signal-slot definition:

```
QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Return),
                    self.comboBox_cmd,
                    activated=self.queryLine)
```

...and the slot:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def queryLine(self):
    '''
    Read cmd string from widget and write to device.
    '''
    ## comboBox can be enhanced with a history
    cmd = self.comboBox_cmd.currentText()
    cmds = [self.comboBox_cmd.itemText(i) for i in range(self.comboBox_cmd.count())]
    if not cmds or cmds[-1] != cmd:
    self.comboBox_cmd.addItem(cmd)
    self.query(cmd)
```

This works really well. Now, how can I mark the entire text of the current item after pressing Enter, so that I can replace the whole line if I so wish?

Comment: By "mark" do you mean select the text? Anyway, why do you use that function? When you press Enter, items that are not already in its model are automatically added.

Comment: Yes, I mean select. It's true, new items are added to the list automatically, this is not my problem. I'm using this box as a command line for a serial device. Sometimes I want to send the same command several times (simply by pressing enter), sometimes I want to send an entirely new command. Right now, I have to delete the last command before I can type new. Having the text selected would mean, I can simply start typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automatically select the text of the line edit by catching the return/enter key press:

```
class SelectCombo(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # call the base class implementation
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        # if return/enter is pressed, select the text afterwards
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
            self.lineEdit().selectAll()
```

Comment: This looks promising, unfortunately I don't know how to make use of it.
I've added your class, and in my GUI class I simply replaced the QComboBox (defined by QtDesigner) as follows in its `__init__`:

    `self.comboBox_cmd = SelectCombo()`

Clearly, this is not enough...

Comment: To clarify: I have now promoted the QComboBox widget to the suggested SelectCombo widget. Everything else in my code is untouched. I've added a simple print function in the keyPressEvent method for simple debugging. The widget is cleary used, but not as expected: Pressing Enter does not trigger the keyPressEvent method, but all other keys do (clearly seen from the prints). However, they do not make the text selected.
I am at a loss here, any further help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you still had the QShortcut, it would "eat" the event. If you want to keep your answer, that's fine, but for future reference wait for answers to your comments, or provide more clarifications, since your new answer doesn't really change what already said in this one, and the fact that you used a custom signal is completely unrelated to the topic at hand.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't find how to catch its enter pressed signal, which I need to act upon in in my GUI. I know, I haven't asked this, so I apologize. I'll accept your answer instead and hope all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got it all assembled :) Problem was, I previously needed to define a shortcut since QComboBox does not have a returnPressed attribute.
With the custom widget, I can change that easily, of course:

```
class SelectCombo(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
'''
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594748/how-to-mark-current-item-text-in-qcombobox/62598381
Modified QComboBox which selects the current text after Enter/Return.
'''
returnPressed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    ## call the base class implementation
    super().keyPressEvent(event)
    ## if return/enter is pressed, select the text afterwards
    if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
        self.lineEdit().selectAll()
        self.returnPressed.emit("Enter pressed!")
```

And in my GUI app, I simply need the following signal-slot definition to make it work:

```
    ## 1) QLineEdit has "returnPressed" but no history
    #self.lineEdit_cmd.returnPressed.connect(self.queryLine)
    ## 2) QComboBox has history, but no "returnPressed" attritbute==> need to define a shortcut
    #QtCore.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Return),
    #QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Return),
    #                    self.comboBox_cmd,
    #                    activated=self.queryLine)
    ## 3) custom SelectCombo widget has QComboBox's history plus "returnPressed"
    self.comboBox_cmd.returnPressed.connect(self.queryLine)
```

Thanks a lot for helping me!